# Probability of a rigged coin

Tags: probability

A loaded coin is tossed once. The occurrence of a head is four times that of a tail.

1. Define the sample space. Find the probability of each outcome.

My answer for this was S= (H,T) the probability of a head is 4/5 and the probability of a tail is 1/5.

2. Two such coins are tossed. Define the sample space. Find the probability of each outcome. Assume the tosses are independent.

My answer was S= (HH, TT, TH, HT)
The probability of a HH is 16/25
The probability of a TT is 1/25
The probability of a TH is 4/25
and the probability of a HT is 4/25

3. Find the probability of getting at most one tail in the previous experiment.

16/25+4/25+4/25=24/25

Could any one correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would slightly modify your notation:  the sample space is a set of elementary outcomes, so rather than using $(H,T)$ I would write $\{H, T\}$ since the use of parentheses in the former case tends to imply that there is an ordering of the terms enclosed--as in how we might write ordered pairs or triplets.  The sample space, however, has no intrinsic ordering and $\{H, T\}$ is equivalent to $\{T, H\}$.

The same applies to the second part.

Everything else looks good.